# Jenkins: Git clone fails with no matching key exchange method found

Tags: git, jenkins, ssh, jenkins-plugins, gerrit

I'm using `Jenkins version - 2.332.1` and i have problem with jenkins gerrit repository ssh clone. The details as follows,

```
Jenkins Git plugin Version 4.10.3
```

**Build server environment:-**

```
$ ssh -V
OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020

$ git --version
git version 2.33.1
```

**Jenkins Build console Log:-**

```
11:35:13  > git config remote.origin.url ssh://prj-user@165.55.66.77:29418/ndk/linux/kernal-image # timeout=10
11:35:13 Fetching upstream changes from ssh://prj-user@165.55.66.77:29418/ndk/linux/kernal-image
11:35:13  > git --version # timeout=10
11:35:13  > git --version # 'git version 2.33.1'
11:35:13  > git fetch --tags --force --progress -- ssh://prj-user@165.55.66.77:29418/ndk/linux/kernal-image +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
11:35:13 ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
11:35:13 hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from ssh://prj-user@165.55.66.77:29418/ndk/linux/kernal-image
11:35:13    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:1001)
11:35:13    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1242)
11:35:13    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1302)
11:35:13    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:540)
11:35:13    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1215)
11:35:13    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:645)
11:35:13    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:85)
11:35:13    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:517)
11:35:13    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1896)
11:35:13    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:44)
11:35:13    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:101)
11:35:13    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:442)
11:35:13 Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --force --progress -- ssh://prj-user@165.55.66.77:29418/ndk/linux/kernal-image +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
11:35:13 stdout: 
11:35:13 stderr: Unable to negotiate with 165.55.66.77 port 29418: no matching key exchange method found. Their offer: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
11:35:13 fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
11:35:13 
11:35:13 Please make sure you have the correct access rights
11:35:13 and the repository exists.
11:35:13 
11:35:13    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2671)
11:35:13    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2096)
11:35:13    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$500(CliGitAPIImpl.java:84)
11:35:13    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:618)
11:35:13    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:999)
11:35:13    ... 11 more
11:35:13 ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
11:35:13 Finished: FAILURE
```

On terminal ssh connection to gerrit works, the result as follows,

```
$ ssh -p 29418 prj-user@165.55.66.77

  ****    Welcome to Gerrit Code Review    ****

  Hi ProUser ., you have successfully connected over SSH.

  Unfortunately, interactive shells are disabled.
  To clone a hosted Git repository, use:

  git clone ssh://prj-user@165.55.66.77:29418/REPOSITORY_NAME.git
```

To solve the problem with jenkins. Kindly help me with the possible workarounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the server where the Jenkins controller is running (assuming it is the same as the one where you tested your ssh connection manually), add to the .bashrc

```
export GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -Tv'
```

That will allow to see exactly what SSH command is run and where it seeks its SSH key pair.

For that, you need to double-check with which account the Jenkins controller is running (root, or the same user account you used yourself for your manual test)

And the issue is also the port used by default is *not* 29418, but 22.

To make sure you are using the right port (again, assuming Jenkins runs with the same user account as the one you are using):

- replace the Gerrit server URL with

  ```
  gerrit:REPOSITORY_NAME.git
  ```
- add a ~/.ssh/config file with:

```
Host gerrit
  Hostname 165.55.66.77
  User prj-user
  Port 29418
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/TheRightPrivateKey
  KexAlgorithms +diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
```

That way, you are sure the SSH URL/command will be the right one, using the right port/key/user/hostname.

Comment: i have created `~/.ssh/config` but now `ssh -p 29418 prj-user@gerrit` works, But `ssh -p 29418 prj-user@165.55.66.77` fails with `Unable to negotiate with 165.55.66.77 port 29418: no matching key exchange method found. Their offer: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1`

Comment: @user4948798 The all idea with a ssh config file is to do `ssh gerrit`, not `ssh -p 1234 user@server`: the config file provides all the information. Make sire to replace `~/.ssh/TheRightPrivateKey` with the actual private key filename.

Comment: @user4948798 Try appending `KexAlgorithms +diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1` under the `IdentityFile` line.